# Tables not rendering correctly in IE 11 and Safari

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, xslt, html-table

I have an xsl page that renders a table for a TON of data. The problem is that for some reason the table isn't rendering properly.

```
<table class="searchresult" style="width:720px;">
<colgroup>
<col style="width:60px;">
<col style="width:100px;">
<col style="width:100px;">
<col style="width:60px;">
<col style="width:220px;">
<col style="width:60px;">
<col style="width:120px;">
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" style="font-weight:bold;">MATLOCK, HARRY<input type="hidden" name="c03-hidden-name__1"><input type="hidden" name="c03-line-color__1"><input name="c03-name-select__1" id="c03nameselect__1" type="hidden"></td>
<td>Record Type: Attorney</td>
<td colspan="2">Status: Active</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4"></td>
<td colspan="3">Company/Firm: </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4"></td>
<td>Work Number: </td>
<td colspan="2">Fax: </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">xxxxxxxx</td>
<td>Bar Code: </td>
<td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

It ends up looking like http://www.weird-girls.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/ie-render-incorrectly1.png

When the header has body data assoiated with it, it looks fine. http://www.weird-girls.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/IE-render-properly1.png

Here's the code with tbody data as well...

```
<table class="searchresult" style="width:720px;">
<colgroup>
<col style="width:60px;">
<col style="width:100px;">
<col style="width:100px;">
<col style="width:60px;">
<col style="width:220px;">
<col style="width:60px;">
<col style="width:120px;">
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr >
<td colspan="4" style="font-weight:bold;">xxxx, xxxxxx xxxxx<input type="hidden" name="c03-hidden-name__1" value="*"><input type="hidden" name="c03-line-color__1" value="DDDDDD"><input name="c03-name-select__1" id="c03nameselect__1" type="hidden"></td>
<td>Record Type: Person</td>
<td colspan="2">DL No: TX:XXXXXXXXXX (CDL) </td>
</tr>
<tr >
<td colspan="4">XXXX XXXXXXX</td>
<td>Birth Place:</td>
<td colspan="2">SSNO:</td>
</tr>
<tr >
<td colspan="4"></td>
<td>Birth Date: 07-12-1984</td>
<td colspan="2">Status: Alive</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">AUSTIN TX 78704</td>
<td>Nationality: </td>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;">Total Due: $317.00</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr style="font-size:14px;">
<td>SRCH</td>
<td>5521816513<input type="hidden" name="c03-hidden-cause__2" value="*"><input type="hidden" name="c03-line-color__2" value="DDDDDD"><input name="c03-cause-select__2" id="c03causeselect__2" type="hidden"></td>
<td></td>
<td>PRL</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td style="text-align:right;">$0.00</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Am I missing something super simple here?

Comment: Can you show your source XML and XSLT stylesheet?

Comment: Please tell me those aren't real peoples details you've got in those picutres? **Those aren't actually peoples court/arrest details are they?**

Comment: @helderdarocha Its not really an XSLT issue, its an issue woth the output HTML thats causing the problem here.

Comment: definitely not real people. these are test data sets

Comment: Why don't you just add an empty `tbody`? Depending on what `DOCTYPE` you use, a table with `thead` without `tbody` can be invalid, so weird browser behavior might have to be expected. Did you check what a validation of the HTML yields?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr those aren't real people. TO make everyone more comfortable I XXXX-ed out data but it's all false data.

Comment: @ThomasW the html validates fine. I've run it through consoles on chrome, IE, Safari, and even Dreamweaver and nothing comes back invalid.

Comment: @ThomasW Adding a blank <tbody> actually messes up the way the page looks but I went ahead and added a <tr> of empty <td> at the end of <thead> and it seems to be working now in all browsers I've done tests on. I guess now my question is why? I've defined the size of all the columns and the table. Shouldn't that work even with empty <colspan>? What makes it necessary to have a defined <td> in order for the defined widths to render like expected? Really trying to figure this out. But THANK YOU for sparking a solution, even though I don't understand why.